# How to do the nested enumeration in the table which was build through the div elements?

Tags: html, css

I want to build a table on the base of `div` elements. In the table I want to show the *ordered numeration* of groups and subgroups. I want to do it through the CSS3 styles.

[image]

My code:

```css
div{
  border-width:0;
}
.table, .group, .row, .column1, .column2{
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:black;
}

.table{
  border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
}

.group, .group .row {
  border-top-width:1px;
}

.row .row{
  border-bottom-width:1px;
}

.row{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.column1{
  border-right-width:1px;
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.column2{
  flex-basis: 1; /* take remaining space */
}

.column1, .column2{
  text-align:left;
}

.group{
  text-align:center;
}

.title{
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="title">Colors</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">I like it</div>
      <div class="column2">Red</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">I like it more</div>
      <div class="column2">Green</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">This is nice too</div>
      <div class="column2">Blue</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="title">Hardware</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">Good choice</div>
      <div class="column2">Display</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">Yes</div>
      <div class="column2">Keyboard</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">Ok</div>
      <div class="column2">mouse</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">Good device</div>
      <div class="column2">videocard</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I do such numeration through the CSS3 styles?  Thank you.

Comment: I do not think that word thinks what you think it means: [enumeration](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/enumeration) - https://youtu.be/YIP6EwqMEoE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CSS Counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

```
.table {
  counter-reset: section;                            /*  reset "section" counter  */
}
.group {
  counter-increment: section;                        /*  increment "section" counter  */
  counter-reset: item;                               /*  reset "item" counter  */
}
.group .title::before {
  content: counter(section) ". ";                    /*  output "item" counter  */
}
.group > div > div:nth-child(1)::before {
  counter-increment: item;                           /*  increment "item" counter  */
  content: counter(section) "." counter(item) "." ;  /*  output "item" counter  */
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
div{
  border-width:0;
}
.table, .group, .row, .column1, .column2{
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:black;
}

.table {
  counter-reset: section;
}
.group {
  counter-increment: section;
  counter-reset: item;
}
.group .title::before {
  content: counter(section) ". ";
}
.group > div > div:nth-child(1)::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(section) "." counter(item) "." ;
}


.table{
  border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
}

.group, .group .row {
  border-top-width:1px;
}

.row .row{
  border-bottom-width:1px;
}

.row{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.column1{
  border-right-width:1px;
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.column2{
  flex-basis: 1; /* take remaining space */
}

.column1, .column2{
  text-align:left;
}

.group{
  text-align:center;
}

.title{
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="title">Colors</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">I like it</div>
      <div class="column2">Red</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">I like it more</div>
      <div class="column2">Green</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">This is nice too</div>
      <div class="column2">Blue</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="title">Hardware</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">Good choice</div>
      <div class="column2">Display</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">Yes</div>
      <div class="column2">Keyboard</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">Ok</div>
      <div class="column2">mouse</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column1">Good device</div>
      <div class="column2">videocard</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```